# How to reomve particular tag and its value firm html content in selenium using java

Tags: java, html, selenium, testng

I want to remove a h1 tag value from body content (html page)   for that
Im using String h1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='tab_content active']/h1")).getText();                                        String content = cont.replace(h1,"");
but by this way   it is removing all the matching text from the content and the particular h1 tag
can anyone suggest how to do this

Answer (score 1):

```
String h1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='tab_content active']/h1")).getText(); 

String content = cont.replace("<h1>"+h1+"</h1>","<h1></h1>");
```

It will remove the particular h1 tag text

Comment: Thanks for the response but  with this its not removing the h1 tag value

Comment: you just replace it from the value to only empty value will be remain